# Make variable inside of a function available for other functions and strings to use

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, jsonp

I have a variable "mediaId" declared yet in my console it keeps telling me that it is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var mediaId;

//load the XML!
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '10461632.xml', // path to XML file
    dataType: "xml", 
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).find('Root').each(function(){

            $(this).find('Item').each(function(){
            mediaId = $(this).attr('videoMediaId'); // get the mediaId
            console.log(mediaId);

            });

        });
    }
});
```

in my "jsonApiCall" var it tells me it is undefined.

```
var jsonpApiCall = "http://www.domain.com/search_media/?format=jason&school=" + vid_partner + "&media_id=" + mediaId + '';
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hava you tried to debug this code ?

Comment: Your var seems to never be defined !?

Comment: Your `mediaId` will store `videoMediaId` of the last `Item`, are you sure it is defined ?

Comment: I want mediaId to store whatever is in videoMediaId, am I not doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define mediaId in the scope that is available to  jsonpApiCall assignment.
+
mediaId must get its value before use.

Try change the line

```
var mediaId;
```

into

```
var mediaId = "";
```

Do you got the same error now ? if yes move mediaId definition in upper scope.

Comment: This actually does not work. It is not capturing the mediaId inside the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would be more sure if you posted the full code, but as I understand you ask for a XML who will assign the variable when it arrives but before it arrives you are trying to use it:

1. You ask for XML
2. You use the variable "mediaId"
3. The XML arrives and then the "mediaId" is assigned.

To prevent this you must not use the "mediaId" outside the callback, everything who uses it must be inside the callback.

Comment: To be sure you can put a console.log() when the variable is assigned and another console.log() when it's used, then you will see which sentence is executed first.